# Override a single partial of TYPO3 fluid_styled_content

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, fluid-styled-content

I want to add `class="img-responsive"` to the markup of each media element of text/media content elements.

I found a corresponding section in fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Partials/MediaGallery.html and added the class for test: Bingo.

```
<f:section name="media">
    <f:media
        file="{column.media}"
        width="{column.dimensions.width}"
        height="{column.dimensions.height}"
        alt="{column.media.alternative}"
        title="{column.media.title}"
        additionalConfig="{settings.media.additionalConfig}"
        class="img-responsive"
    />
</f:section>
```

I guess adding a custom partialRootPath with `lib.fluidContent.partialRootPaths.200` and copying all the partials would work [as documented](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/fluid_styled_content/7.6/Configuration/OverridingFluidTemplates/).

However, I'd like to avoid copying 20 partials from fluid_styled_content just to change one line in one file.

Can I override a single partial of TYPO3 fluid_styled_content, or even better a single section of the partial?

Using TYPO3 7.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Set `lib.contentElement.partialRootPaths.200 = EXT:your_extension_key/Resources/Private/Partials/` in TypoScript as described in the question.
2. Copy a **single** partial file `MediaGallery.html` from fluid_styled_content to `EXT:your_extension_key/Resources/Private/Partials/`
3. Have enough breaks during work to avoid stackoverflow.

Comment: @bob-der-baumeister The original answer referred to TYPO3 7.6. So `lib.fluidContent.partialRootPaths.200 =` was the correct answer. Better add a paragraph that the path changed to `lib.contentElement` with TYPO3 version [add version here]. Keep this in mind when editing future posts.